# Sounds not always playing when I use VC6

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++-6

I am studying the Windows programming by using the book

> Programming.Windows.5th.Edition(Charles Petzold).

When I doing the **Figure 3-1. The HELLOWIN program**,I find that when I use the hotkey ctrl+F5 to run the exe,I can hear the sound(Hello windows 98),but when I run the exe in the directory Debug,no sound could be heard.After putting the exe together with HelloWin.wav,everything is OK.How could this happen?I am using the win7(simplified Chinese Edition) and Visual Studio 6(Enterprise Edition.)

[image]

Comment: The avatar is generated from your e-mail address (I've removed that part from your question at it's not relevant)

Comment: @ChrisF,you mean that the avatar is a kind of thing like QR codes?

Comment: All I know is that it's an image generated from your e-mail address. I don't know whether you can reverse engineer the e-mail from the image. That's a question in its own right!

Comment: FYI default avatars are Identicons http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this is an issue of relative paths. My guess is that you refer to the .wav file using a relative path and just name it `"HelloWin.wav"`. This is relative to the current directory.

When you double click the .exe the current directory is the exe directory and the .wav is not found. When you press <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> from the IDE, the IDE sets the current directory to be the project directory and thus the file is found.

Comment: Thank you!!I suddenly remember I met this kind of problem when I using TC.

Answer (score 2):

It's all to do with **current directories**. When executing it from Visual Studio, it will use the *project* directory as the current directory and so your program will find the wav file in that directory.

When you run the exe directly, it will use the Debug directory as the current directory and ,since the wav file is not in there, not find the sound file.

Comment: Thank you!!I suddenly remember I met this kind of problem when I using TC.